# double question mark vs && in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

here's what the purpose of using `??`

```
//Similar to || but only returns the right-hand operand if the left-hand is null or undefined
0 ?? "other" // 0
false ?? "other" // false
null ?? "other" // "other"
undefined ?? "other" // "other"
```

but I normally use `&&`, so what's the difference?

Comment: Relevant: [When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61480993) Overall, the sentiment is the same - do you want to handle *only* `null` and `undefined` or also other falsy values.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm asking `??` vs `&&`

Comment: Again, do you want to handle all falsy values or only `null` and `undefined`? Because that's what the difference is.

Comment: @SandraAnderson, I [specifically answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143185/8910547) your question about `??` vs `&&` :)