# Javascript check if object by Id is in array

Tags: javascript

I have a single id and I need to check if it is in an array of objects. Example,

```
id = 2;

const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'James'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 3, name: 'Mike'}]
```

is there a javascript function that does this? I cant find one online the includes() method only compares if the object is in the array not if there is a property in an object exists

Comment: I need it to return true if it is else false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a value in an array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: That answer returns the entire object or undefined but I just need a true or false

Comment: Array#some() returns boolean

Comment: Do you have an example in this case using array.some()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let id = 3;
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'James'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Peter'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Mike'
}]

var chek = arr.find(c => c.id === id);

console.log(chek ?? "Not present")
//or:
if (chek === undefined) {
  console.log("Not present")
} else {
  console.log(chek.name)
}
```

[When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to charlietfl for pointing out that `find()` is more efficient than `filter()` if you only care that a match exists and don't need each matching instance.

You can use the `find()` method to check for the existance of an element that matches your conditions. If an element is not found, the `containsId` variable will be undefined.

```js
var id = 2;
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'James'}, {id: 2, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 3, name: 'Mike'}];

// Find the first element in the array
// whose id is equal to 2.
var containsId = arr.find(x => x.id === id);

// Log (or return) whether or not we found
// an element.
console.log(containsId !== undefined);
```

Comment: Using some() or find() is more efficient since they break when condition met and don't require generating a new array