# Shorter way to write a ternary operator in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

So hear me out, I feel like there has to be a way, but I am really unsure.

Let's say I have this in my react project

```
{name ? name : "no name"}
```

but I am wondering if it were possible to somehow write this short to return the first value if true otherwise return the second value? something like this

```
{name ! "no name"}
```

I feel like there has to be a way to do it, I am just curious if anyone knows how?

Answer (score 3):

Use the logical *OR*: `||`

```js
const name = '';
const test1 = name ? name : "no name";
const test2 = name || "no name";

console.log(test1, test2);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

---

For more info about `??` vs `||` please take a look at:

[When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or)

Comment: Thankyou! What is a better way to do this? nullish operator to the logical or?

Comment: @NickH - See my comment on the other answer (where your comment asking this seems to have disappeared).

Comment: @NickH That depends on what you would consider a valid value for the name: a "logical or" `||` would use the second value if the first one is *falsy* (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `''`) while the "nullish coalescing" `??` would use the second value if the first one is... well *nullish* (either `null` or `undefined`). An empty string is falsy but not nullish, `0` is falsy but not nullish, etc... so you use one or the other, depending on whether you want to accept or not all falsy but not nullish values.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
{ name ?? "no name" }
```

Comment: Or { name || "no name" }, in certain situations

Comment: @NickH - It depends on A) Does your target environment support nullish coalescing? (It's relatively new.) And B) Do you want **all** [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (`0`, `""`, etc.) to be skipped in favor of `"no name"` (use `||`) or just `null` and `undefined` (use `??`)?