# Is there a better way to check for a null and assign a value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a better / smarter way to do this?

```
theTitle = responsesToUse[i]["Title"];

if(theTitle == null)
  theTitle = "";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). Returns the right side if the left side is `null` or `undefined`:

```
const theTitle = responsesToUse[i]["Title"] ?? "Default value";
```

Additionally you can use the [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). It will check if left value is `falsy` and return the right side:

```
const theTitle = responsesToUse[i]["Title"] || "Default value";
```

This question [is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or)

Comment: the _falsy_ check is misleading in this case, because it can misinterpret valid `0` or `""` values.

Answer (score -1):

```
theTitle = responsesToUse[i]["Title"] ?? "";
```

Comment: code only answers and code with typos are not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator can be used:

```
const theTitle = responsesToUse?.[i]?.["Title"] || "";
```

use `?.` to check if the required `index`/ `property` exist in the source, else fallback to right side value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: probably the downvoter thought that the falsy check is misleading in this case, because it can misinterpret valid 0 or "" values.