# add null value for proprties which do not exist in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I want to add null values for properties which are non existent in the array of objects. I don't want to loop over

```
var data=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

Expected result is as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": null
    }
]
```

Comment: you have to loop over. even if you use `map`

Answer (score 0):

Map array so if name is undefined set it to null, otherwise leave the same value:

```
const result = data.map(item => ({...item, name: item.name ?? null}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Little for each loop will do that. Also I think `||` would be better than `??`, here is why:
[When should I use ?? (nullish coalescing) vs || (logical OR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or)

```js
const data =[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]

data.forEach(set => { set.name = set.name || null })
console.log(data)
```

Ah sorry, didn't notice the part with the loop in the question. I still let this answer be here.

Answer (score 0):

One further option is the following, with explanatory comments in the code; this answer assumes that the keys may have to be found prior to adding them to the Object:

```js
// the initial Array of Objects:
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  }
],

// a simple function, declared using Arrow function syntax,
// which takes one argument, an Array of Objects:
getAllKeys = (objectArray) => {

  // we return an Array formed from a Set, by use of the
  // spread syntax and an Array literal:
    return [...new Set(
        // we form the Set from the reduced Array of Objects,
        // created using Array.prototype.reduce():
        objectArray.reduce(
          // the Array.prototype.reduce() method has the
          // arguments of 'acc' (the accumulator formed
          // by the method), and the 'curr' Object (the
          // current Object of the Array of Objects):
          (acc,curr) => {
            // within the Arrow function, we simply
            // push the keys of the current Object -
            // retrieved with Object.keys - to the
            // accumulator Array, which we then flatten
            // using Array.prototype.flat():
            acc.push(Object.keys(curr));
          return acc.flat();
        // the empty Array-literal here is the accumulator
        // used within the method:
        },[]
      )
    )];
  },
// here we use the function to retrieve an Array of the
// keys from Objects in the data Array:
keys = getAllKeys(data),

// we then use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the
// data Array and create a new Array from that Array:
newData = data.map((obj) =>{
  // we return a new Object, created using Object.fromEntries():
    return Object.fromEntries(
    // we use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the
    // Array of Object properties:
    keys.map(
      // 'k' is the value of the current Object property
      // ('k' standing for 'key' in this case);
      // we return a new two-part Array formed from the
      // current Object property-name, and the existing
      // property-value of the current Object's property
      // of that name, or null (if no property-value
      // exists):
      (k)=> [k, obj[k] || null]
    )
  );
});

console.log(newData);
/*
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: null
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: null
    }
  ]

*/
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rk1g62jd/).

References:

- Array-literals.
- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).